# There is any way to disable start and stop bit in serial communication on Linux?

Tags: serial-port, embedded-linux, uart

I need a serial communication in 'raw' mode when only the data byte will be transmitted . The purpose is transmitting information using any RF tx module to boards around using bi-phase codification. The start e stop bit don't permit do this with flexibility.

Comment: They are generated by the hardware, like a UART chip, software doesn't have anything to do with it.  Ask the board vendor for support.

Comment: You cannot remove the start and stop bits from an asynchronous character **frame**; otherwise it will not work.  You may be  misunderstanding this RF module's interface.